# Using != gets me different results when using NOT IN in SQL

Tags: sql

When I use the != operator in a SQL query multiple times in the WHERE statement of a query, it doesn't appear to work, however when I use NOT IN operator it does work. Me and my colleague looked at it and we can't figure out why.

This is a query that will select records from a table that does not contain certain values, hence why I was using NOT IN and !=.

```
-- With NOT IN (this works).

SELECT SUM(ACTUAL_COST_FW) 
FROM COSTINGS_FW
WHERE COSTINGS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW = '1234' AND
COSTING_CODE_FW NOT IN ('TYRES-P', 'TYRES-L', 'TYRES-E-P', 'TYRES-E-L', 
'ROADTAX', 'MISC', 'LEASE', 'INSURANCE', 'FUEL', 'DP', 'ACCIDENT')

-- Without NOT IN (this doesn't work).

SELECT SUM(ACTUAL_COST_FW) 
FROM COSTINGS_FW
WHERE COSTINGS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW = '1234' AND
(COSTING_CODE_FW != 'TYRES-P' OR 
COSTING_CODE_FW != 'TYRES-L' OR 
COSTING_CODE_FW != 'TYRES-E-P' OR 
COSTING_CODE_FW != 'TYRES-E-L' OR 
COSTING_CODE_FW != 'ROADTAX' OR 
COSTING_CODE_FW != 'MISC' OR 
COSTING_CODE_FW != 'LEASE' OR 
COSTING_CODE_FW != 'INSURANCE' OR 
COSTING_CODE_FW != 'FUEL' OR 
COSTING_CODE_FW != 'DP' OR 
COSTING_CODE_FW != 'ACCIDENT')
```

With the multiple != operators with 'OR' keyword it will return a record  (that contains '1234' within the 'VEHICLE_ID_FW' field) that I know also contains 'TYRES-L' within the field 'COSTING_CODE_FW' however when I use the 'NOT IN' operator it doesn't return that record as it should. Any ides why?

Comment: Use `AND`, as in: `(COSTING_CODE_FW != 'TYRES-P' AND COSTING_CODE_FW != 'TYRES-L'`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `OR`s should be `AND`s.  If something is equal to 'TYRES-P', then it is not equal to the next value.  The `OR`ed expressions always product TRUE -- unless the column is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE col NOT IN ('p', 'b', 'c')
```

equvalent

```
WHERE col <> 'p'
AND col <> 'b'
AND col <> 'c';
```

so you have to use `AND` instead `or` inside